# RoR Show name instead id of a self-join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, self-join

This is my first time here!
I hope nobody get mad with my question, I started studing rails just fews days ago.

The question is:

I got a model students wiht :id, :name, :email, :phone and :id_indicator wich is FK of id.
I would like to show tha NAME of the INDICATOR instead the ID of INDICATOR.

```
<td><%= student.id%></td>
<td><%= student.name %></td>
<td><%= student.email %></td>
<td><%= student.phone %></td>
<td><%= student.id_indicator%></td> ---> I want to show the NAME here
```

How can I do that?

Thanks all!

There is just one model STUDENT. Its a self-relationship table.
I have students refering students.

The SQL query for that would be like:

```
select name from **students** where id = ( select id_indicator from **students** where id = 10)
```

Example:
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kgfX.png

Comment: what are the relationships between `indicator` and `student` ?

Comment: id_indicator is the FK of id in student table.
Its a table self reference.

id_indicator references id

Comment: i gave out a answer, check it out and tell me if it fits you, and if not i we will try to figure it out

Comment: check that: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7kgfX.png

Comment: so one employee belongs to one manager and one manager has many employees?

Comment: One student can indicate many students and the student is indicated for just one student

Comment: i updated my answer, although still not sure what the word `indicate` means :))

Comment: okay.. do you need further assistance or is it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One student can indicate many students and the student is indicated
>   for just one student

```
class Aluno < ActiveRecord::Base 
    attr_accessible :email, :id, :id_indicator, :name, :profession, :gender, :phone

    belongs_to :indicator, class_name: "Aluno", :foreign_key => "id_indicator"
    has_many :indicates, class_name: "Aluno", :foreign_key => "id_indicator"
end
```

When you want to see the name of the person that indicated the student:

```
<%= student.indicator.name %>
```

or if you want to find all the students that the student indicated you can do:

```
<% student.indicates.each do |indicate| %>
     <%= indicate.name %>
<% end %>
```

For more info checkout rails guides or railscasts

Comment: Zippie, sorry for my non-sense questions.
It's my first time here and my english is too bad!

Comment: Let's try again.

imagine John is a student of School XXX and tell you to stud there too.
When you get there to apply, you tell then that JOHN indicated you to stud there. So, your profile will say that you were indicated by JOHN.
Did you understand? Lol

Comment: You know? It's like to have your ID and the ID_father in person table.
You have just one father, but your father can be in more than one person. If you have brothers or sisters.

Comment: undefined method `name' for 13:Fixnum

The id_indicator is a integer and nome is a string

Comment: please checkout the guides and checkout this tutorial, i can't help you anymore i have other stuff to do. http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

Comment: Good luck! BTW. just realised, it should be `:class_name => "Aluno"`

Comment: Thanks Zippie!
I was having a problem with a f*** NULL!

Everything is ok now!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Please show us your models, but it should be as easy as:

```
<%= student.indicator.name %>
```

Comment: class Aluno < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :email, :id, :id_indicator, :name, :profession, :gender, :phone

end

It's justa one model. Same table.

Comment: Please add in your question both the `Student` and `Indicator` models.